# Return multiple resolver from Angular - beginner

Tags: angular

This is a 2 part question:

I need to return multiple Resolvers. When the user loads the user-List I want to call `getusers()` and when the user search for a user then I need to load `getiusers(id)`.

1. The following code doesn't work. How can i call multiple service methods from the `Resolver` ? (May be a If-Else method ?)
2. How to pass the `id` from the component to the resolver ?

   ```
    export class UserResolver implements Resolve<any> {
       resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

           return this.userservice.getusers();
   },

       resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

           return this.userservice.getiusers(id);
   }
   ```

**UPDATE**

```
   {
      path: 'user',
      component: UserComponent,
      resolve: { user: UserResolver }
    },
```

Comment: You might need two different resolvers, and two different routes. One without a parameter which loads `getusers()`, and a second route with a parameter which uses `getiusers(id)`. Where `id` would be a route parameter.

Comment: You mean 2 separate classes ?

Comment: Yes, resolvers can not be configured (at least not easily). So it's often easier to just create two different resolver classes, but that depends upon how you've defined your routes. Can you update your question to show how the resolver is being used with your routes.

Comment: I have updated my post with code for Routes. Can you also tell me how to pass the parameter `id` from Component to the Resolver ?